# How can I plot two lines in the same graph from Excel using Pandas and Matplotlib?

Tags: python, excel

I want to read an Excel file, sum the values for the years 2021, 2020 and 2019 for the locations from the same region (region B) and then create a graph with two lines (for region A and B) which will show how the values for both regions have changed during the years.

I tried with this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

excel_file_path = "Testfile.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file_path)

x = ["2021", "2020", "2019"]    

y1 = df_region["Values2021"]
y2 = df_region["Values2020"]
y3 = df_region["Values2019"]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))

plt.plot(x, y1, color = 'red', label = "A")
plt.plot(x, y2, color = 'blue', label = "B")

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

But it isn't working for me - I get the following error:

"Exception has occurred: ValueError
x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (3,) and (2,)"

What do I need to do to get the result that I want? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you meant to define your `y1` and `y2` a little differently.

```
x = ["2021", "2020", "2019"]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,5))
colors = ['red', 'blue']

for i, region in enumerate(df_region.index):
    y = df_region.loc[region, :]
    plt.plot(x, y, color = colors[i], label = region)

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

which plots AND reads the region names from the DataFrame.

[image]

Comment: Thank you but I want to read the names of the regions (A or B) directly from the Excel file without defining them inside my code. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Ok.  I edited the code to read the region names directly from the DataFrame.  If you have more region names, you'll have to provide more colors in the color list.  If the result answers your question, please mark the solution as accepted.